# clojurecademy, thread macro challenge

Tags: clojure

I'm currently working through clojurecademy and came across this problem which I can't seem to solve -

```
(= (#_blank (sort (rest (reverse [2 5 4 1 3 6]))))
   (-> [2 5 4 1 3 6] (reverse) (rest) (sort) (#_blank))
   5)
```

I only need to enter enough to fill in the blank, at first I thought it was just asking me to write what these functions would return, which I think would be (1 2 3 4 5) but that's not correct, I can't figure out why there is a 5 passed in the the equal function, I was thinking maybe I needed to add a function that references 5 from the returned list but I'm not sure how to do that either (without a defined variable) I could be way off...

This is clojurecademy, Problems - Elementary question number 23

Comment: in case this is what is bothering you, `=` can test equality on more than 2 arguments (it test if they are all equal)

Comment: I see, but as far as I can tell the first two eval to - (1 2 3 4 5) and the last argument is 5, feeling confused about how they are all supposed to be equal?

Comment: Ah I think I see, I have to add a function which takes 5 from the returned list?

Comment: Be lazy! just replace the #_blank with `(constantly 5)` )))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The challenge is to make each expression return 5.

As [=](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/=) can take multiple values for equality, Clojure Academy have included 5 within the check too ensure the two expresions you need to complete also return 5.

I would recommend trying to get this expression to return 5

```
(#_blank (sort (rest (reverse [2 5 4 1 3 6]))))
```

then work on the next expression to return 5.

Comment: I see but the only way I can think to do that is with (nth [col] index) but how do I pass the list in?

Comment: A good trick is to evaluate each expression individually. So evaluate `(reverse [2 5 4 1 3 6])` and seeing what that returns then `(rest (reverse [2 5 4 1 3 6]))` and so on. Then once you finally get to `(sort (rest (reverse [2 5 4 1 3 6])))` look at that result and work out what how you could possible get 5 from that value. https://clojuredocs.org/ is a great resource to discover all of Clojure's standard functions which could help achieving that.

Comment: Amazing thanks for helping me understand that, I used - last

Comment: :) clojuredocs.org is a great resource for finding and understanding all of Clojure's standard library.